# low power alternatives to LM741?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-power, bipolar

I am trying to build a triangle wave generator and the op-amp that kept getting recommended was the LM741. However, according to the datasheet I found, I need to have at least a 10V source to power the op-amp. This is a problem because I plan on using an arduino to power it. Are there any low-power alternatives to the LM741 or am I just misreading the datasheet?

Just to be clear, the requirements I am looking for are: Bipolar voltage inputs, bipolar outputs, minimum supply voltage < 5V.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are litterally hundreds of products that meet these requirements (which are under-specified in your post, by the way). Look at manufacturers websites, distributors (mouser, digikey,...). And shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: This can possibly be turned into a non-shopping question by asking "how to find a low power alternative to the LM741".

Comment: The 741 was old hat in my day - and that's many **decades ago**.  Even the humble LM358 would give you better performance (3 - 32V supply range) and you get two op amps in that package - useful for a triangle wave generator.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to find an op amp that meets your requirements.

For one, the [LM741 page on ti.com](http://www.ti.com/product/LM741?keyMatch=LM741&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything) lists some alternatives:

[image]

The first, the [LM7301](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7301.pdf), appears to meet your requirements. It's rail-to-rail input and output, though, which might be overkill for you.

More generally, you can search all the op amps offered by an IC manufacturer on the manufacturer's website. For example, [there are 50 bipolar op amps offered by TI with a minimum supply voltage of 5V or less](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/space-high-reliability/amplifier/operational-amplifiers-products.page#p1261min=1.1;5&p89=Bipolar).

If you don't want to search each IC manufacturer's website individually, you can also search the websites of distributors like Digikey, Mouser, etc. For example, [there are 1,857 op amps with a minimum supply voltage of 5V or less on Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/2556125?k=&pkeyword=&pv659=271&pv659=34&pv659=248&pv659=254&pv659=253&pv659=203&pv659=249&pv659=408&pv659=113&pv659=26&pv659=255&pv659=245&pv659=1166&pv659=84&pv659=406&pv659=25&pv659=851&pv659=114&pv659=853&pv659=453&pv659=8&pv659=350&pv659=464&pv659=898&pv659=689&pv659=112&pv659=67&pv659=206&pv659=135&pv659=864&pv659=919&pv659=28&pv659=359&pv659=154&pv659=779&pv659=867&pv659=56&pv659=256&pv659=364&pv659=161&pv659=1191&pv659=116&pv659=372&pv659=58&pv659=176&pv659=498&pv659=127&pv659=315&pv659=468&pv659=491&pv659=163&pv659=494&pv659=43&pv659=162&pv659=914&pv659=87&pv659=85&pv659=202&pv659=1194&FV=fff40027%2Cfff800dd&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) (though they're not necessarily all bipolar -- I can't find a way to filter by architecture on Digikey).

The difficulty will not be in finding a replacement op amp for your requirements, but in selecting a particular op amp out of all the many possibilities. The LM741 is an old op amp and most modern op amps are superior to it in performance. You'll probably end up choosing a particular op amp based on package and price.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know how well the LM741 perfored at 5V, so I just replaced the LM741 in a circuit of mine with the [NE5532](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NE5532-D.PDF) because I wanted to power the amp with 5V. (The NE5532 datasheet states that VCC+ a should be between 5 and 15V.)

The NE5532's profile is the same as the LM741, though the pinout is different (in fact the 8-pin NE5532 has 2 amps in it), but the characteristics were similar enough for me. It's cheap and avilable in many places. It's commonly used in audio applications and has bipolar inputs.

Edit: There is also the sister chip, [NE5534](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5534.pdf), which is almost the same IC but with a single op-amp. Because of this, it has slightly less noise and power consumption, [along with some other differences](http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/parts/113556-ne5532-vs-ne5534.html). It also has a more similar pinout to the L741.

Comment: The NE5532 and NE5534 need +/-5V supplies, or 10 volts total. They probably won't work at +5/0V.

The LM358 (dual) and LM324 (quad) are popular low-cost opamps that will work at +5/0 volts.

Comment: @RichS -  The datasheet for them at ti.com says that they can be used as single or dual supply. Am I misunderstanding what that means?